# Problems with i18n with Play App 2.4.6

Tags: scala, playframework

I have one simple project with Play Framework 2.4.6 that have internationalization configured as documentation on Play describe.
My files are that:
1) Controller:

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.i18n.{I18nSupport,MessagesApi,Messages,Lang}
import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._
import play.api.Play.current
import javax.inject.Inject

class Application @Inject()(val messagesApi: MessagesApi) extends Controller with  I18nSupport {

  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

}
```

2) Message resource file:

```
application.name = Orthoclinic
welcome = Welcome to play!
```

3) Main template:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit messages: Messages)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("/assets/stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("/assets/images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("/assets/javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @Messages("application.name")
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

4) Index template:

```
@(message: String)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    @play20.welcome(message)


}
```

5) routes file:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

6) Application conf file:

```
play.crypto.secret = "k1mIneaPlay_pRoJ"
play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "en-us", "pt-br", "es" ]



Calling ./activator reload compile run my result is that:
[error] /home/josenildo/scala-ide/workspace/orthoclinic-app/app/views/main.scala.html:13: could not find implicit value for para
meter messages: play.api.i18n.Messages
[error]         @Messages("application.name")
```

I have followed the documentation for i18n last version on Play Documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24).
What's the problem on that implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the implicit `messages` argument to your `index.scala.html` template:

```
@(message: String)(implicit messages: Messages)

@main("Welcome to Play") {

    @play20.welcome(message)
}
```

An implicit `Messages` instance needs to be in-scope whenever you use i18n via `@Messages("my.key")`, which has a corresponding implicit `messages` argument that will be supplied by the compiler (see the signature [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.i18n.Messages$@apply(keys:Seq[String],args:Any*)(implicitmessages:play.api.i18n.Messages):String)).

**Also**, you may want to get rid of `import play.api.i18n.Messages.Implicits._`, since it shouldn't be required if your controller extends `I18NSupport`, and indeed may cause an error concerning ambiguous implicit values.

Comment: The problem is not on index.scala.html is on main.scala.html. the parameter message on index.scala.html is load on controller it's functioning. The problem is for load messages on main.scala.html that is the main entry point for templates. The error is clear is on main.scala.html template.

Comment: Did you actually try it?

Comment: The unique form that resolved that was: Altering the controller assign with: ` class Products (at)Inject() extends Controller`. Altering play.i18n.langs = [ "en", "en-us", "pt-br", "es" ] for application.langs= "en,es,fr,nl,pt-br" and altering on main.scala.html @Messages for @messages. Now is functioning with that.